# gnuradio signal probe c++

Tags: c++, gnuradio

I'm trying to implement Carrier Sensing in a C++ block in GNU Radio. The Signal Probe block seems to be able to probe the input signal, but how can the results of this probe be accessed in my C++ block?

I imagine, that inside my C++ block, I have to use the name of signal probe (or Function Probe) to find a pointer to it.

Comment: I don't know much about gnu radio, so it may be something simple; but I imagine some code would aid in understanding the "how must I use the code" question. Is there something of a [mcve] to supplement this question?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why would you do that? the purpose of having your own block is usually to process the signal yourself. I suspect there's something one would design slightly different. Can you illustrate the flowgraph you're building?